# How to get HTML tags displayed in LaTeX?

Tags: html

I am making a LaTeX document and I am having HTML tags like `List<? extends Number>` which when I put in LaTeX turn out to be `List¡? extends Number¿`. I tried escaping with `\` but did not help. Anybody knows how to escape `<` and `>` in LaTeX?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The LaTeX expressions to insert `<` and `>` would be `\textless` and `\textgreater`.

In a `verbatim` environment you can also include such characters without escaping. To properly include HTML code I would suggest that you have a [look into the listings or lstlistings package](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Source_Code_Listings).

Answer (score 4):

```
\documentclass[preview,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\begin{document}
< you must use T1 font encoding >
\end{document}
```

[image]